# AsyncTask to get xml

Tags: android

I want to use AsynTask to do custom list with xml from url. I am novice so I don´t know how to structure this properly. When the fragment start doesn´t display nothing. I am using Swipe views with fragments but I don´t know how correct the issue

```
public class UltimasFragment extends Fragment {

static final String URL = "http://myurl.com/songs";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_SONG = "songs"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "id_song";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "name";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "picture";
static final String KEY_ARTIST = "duration";


View view;
ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;


private ProgressDialog dialog;
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ultimas, container, false);

        new MiTarea().execute();

        list=(ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lista);

        // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
        //adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList); 

        adapter=new LazyAdapter(getActivity(), songsList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Click event for single list row
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                  String idrecibida =songsList.get(+position).get("id_song");
                  String nombrerecibido =songsList.get(+position).get("name");
                  String caratularecibida =songsList.get(+position).get("picture");
                  String nuestraoprecibida =songsList.get(+position).get("duration");


            }
        }); 


        return view;

}


private class MiTarea extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        dialog.setMessage("Actualizando...");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.show();
     }

     protected String doInBackground(String... args) {



        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element


        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);


        // looping through all song nodes <song>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
            map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));
            map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));


            songsList.add(map);




        }
        return xml;


     }


     protected void onPostExecute(String bytes) {
         dialog.dismiss();
      // adding HashList to ArrayList




     }
}
```

}

Comment: you are interacting with UI elements inside of `doInBackground` method of your AsyncTask, but [doInBackground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground(Params...)) doesn't run in UI Thread. This will make trouble at some point

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to impement async task

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

The preExecute method allow you to perform operations before starting the job you want to do asyncronously.

the doInBackground method is here to do your async job.

the on postExecute method will receive what doInBackground returns if it returns something.

if you need to pass parameters to your class like a context, my advice is to make a constructor and passing parameters to it ;)

hope it helped.

regards.

Comment: Thank you, yes but I don´t know how use this properly

Comment: do not manipulate UI elements in doInBackground but just data. if you need to manipuate UI elements, do it on postExecute ;)

Comment: Some help with my code? what I´m doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: You define listener in your asyncTask, this is not a good pratice at all. there is no doubt that you can find a way to avoid that ;) you shoud make the call to you async task, one you task is done, start the activity which is supposed to display the listview by passing you data (your parsed XML). this is gonna be way much cleaner if you define your listener is the activity itself ;) am i clear ? to shematise, here is how it goes : activity => async task with (get your xml and parse it) => pass your data to the new activity => set your listener and everything you need. does it sound nice ?

Comment: I appreciate your help but I don´t understand because I am novice. Can you explain me using my code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The three parameters are: the parameter type of doInBackground, the parameter type of onProgressUpdate and the parameter type of onPostExecute.

See here the usage:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Remember to call setReteainInstance(true) in the fragment in this case, because if the fragment is remove you lost the reference to the AsyncTask.

Comment: Thank you, I have refresh my code, can you help me?